# Branching statements - ascending or descending integers

Tags: java

Been studying Java for a few months now with no prior development experience, but I am determined to learn this. This is my first post. Here's the question:

Write a program that reads a sequence of integer numbers and outputs true if the sequence is ordered (in ascending or descending order), otherwise, false. Keep in mind, if a number has the same value as the following number, it does not break the order.
The sequence ends with 0. Do not consider this number as a part of the sequence. The sequence always has at least one number (excluding 0).

Sample Input 1:
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

Sample Output 1:
true

Sample Input 2:
1 2 3 3 9 0

Sample Output 2:
true

Sample Input 3:
1 2 5 5 2 3 0

Sample Output 3:
false

I've read other posts that addresses this issue, but my code is a representation of the concepts I've learned and quasi-understand thus far. 
My intuition is that in order to iterate through all the values that are input BEFORE producing a 'true' or 'false', a list is probably needed. But, I'm unsure of how to utilize Scanner within a list and how to use a list within a 'for loop' &/or 'if' statements. Here is my code thus far, which is producing a error of time limit exceeded. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i > 0; i++) {

            if (input >= i || input == i + 1) {
            System.out.println(true); 
            }  
            else if (input <= i || input == i - 1) {
            System.out.println(true);
            }
            else {
            System.out.println(false);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You are reading only one number with your one `nextInt()` call. If you want to check all the numbers from the sequence you have to actually have to read all the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first read in all the numbers:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(); //use a list to store
int number = -1;
while(number != 0) { //go until 0
    System.out.println("Enter a positive int or 0 to stop!");
    number = scanner.nextInt(); //read integer
    if(number != 0) {
        numbers.add(number); //save it, but only if it's not 0
    }
}
```

Now we have all numbers in the list. Some methods can be writter to check if they are ascending:

```
public static boolean isAscending(List<Integer> numbers) {
    int number, next;
    if(numbers.size()==1) return true; // edge cases
    if(numbers.size()==2) {
       return numbers.get(0) <= numbers.get(1);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.size() - 2; i++) { //from first to one before last
        number = numbers.get(i);
        next = numbers.get(i+1);
        if(next < number) { //next is NOT bigger then the current (equal accepted)
            return false;        
        }
    }
    return true; //if we got here then it's ascending
}
```

The descending method is similar, but you use '>' when comparing the numbers. Then, it's just a matter of calling them on the input list:

```
boolean ascending = isAscending(numbers);
boolean descending = isDescending(numbers);
if(ascending || descending) {
    //result is TRUE here
    System.out.println("TRUE");
} else {
    //result is FALSE here
    System.out.println("FALSE");
}
```

Comment: Considering the case of input only has one or two numbers.

Comment: @HowieChih Thanks for pointing that out, made an edit for that.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and thorough response. Still a bit shaky on the use of methods and calling those methods since this platform has been focused, up until this point, with achieving the desired outcome in the Main. Though understandably not the best setup, how can I break these methods down to function as part of the Main method?

Comment: @dsg523 Methods isnt something you can live without, better look it up soon. Its simple no worry

Comment: I understand that, but that's not where we're at just yet in this program.